# Python/Telethon on SQLite database operational error: unable to open database file

Tags: python, sqlite, permissions, telethon

I have a python/telethon Telegram bot project consisting of a single python file, an SQLite databse, and a config file. The bot runs fine on my local system in a virtual environment (all three files are in the same directory) but when I attempt to run the python file on ubuntu server, I'm running into the following error.

Project files are in `/usr/local/bin/project/`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/project/script.py", line 19, in <module>
    client = TelegramClient(session_name, API_ID, API_HASH).start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 289, in __init__
    session = SQLiteSession(session)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/telethon/sessions/sqlite.py", line 47, in __init__
    c = self._cursor()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/telethon/sessions/sqlite.py", line 242, in _cursor
    self._conn = sqlite3.connect(self.filename,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Below are the contents of script.py:

```
import configparser
import re
from telethon import TelegramClient, Button, events
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
import traceback

print("Initializing configurations...")
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini', encoding='utf-8')

API_ID = config.get('default','api_id') 
API_HASH = config.get('default','api_hash')
BOT_TOKEN = config.get('default','bot_token')
session_name = "sessions/Bot"

# Start the bot session
client = TelegramClient(session_name, API_ID, API_HASH).start(bot_token=BOT_TOKEN)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="(?i)/start"))
async def start(event):
    
    sender = await event.get_sender()
    SENDER = str(sender.id)
    
    await event.reply('Hello!.')
    
##### MAIN
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print("Initializing Database...")
        # Connect to local database
        db_name = 'database.db'
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name, check_same_thread=False)
        # Create the cursor
        crsr = conn.cursor() 
        print("Connected to the database")

        # Command that creates the "customers" table 
        sql_command = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers ( 
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
            lname VARCHAR(200),
            fname VARCHAR(200), 
            note VARCHAR(200));"""
        crsr.execute(sql_command)
        print("All tables are ready")

        print("Bot Started")
        client.run_until_disconnected()

    except Exception as error:
        print('Cause: {}'.format(error))
```

These are the contents of `config.ini`:

```
; DO NOT MODIFY THE LINE BELOW!!! ([default])
[default]


; EDITABLE FIELDS:
api_id = 000000
api_hash = 000000000000000000
bot_token = 00000000000000000000000000
```

I checked permissions on all three files, and am getting the following:

```
-rw-r--rw- 1 root root 10601 Mar  4 00:52 script.py

-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 716800 Mar  4 00:52 database.db

-rw-r--rw- 1 root root 195 Mar  4 00:52 config.ini
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @KlausD. I've added the contents of all files that still reproduce the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TelegramClient` by default tries to create a sqlite file for stroing the session information.

> The first parameter you pass to the constructor of the TelegramClient is the session, and defaults to be the session name (or full path).
> https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/sessions.html

since you have named your session `"sessions/Bot"`, it tries to find a folder named `"sessions"` and then create a db file named `"Bot"`. But it can't find the folder.

To fix this error, you can either change your `session_name` to just a filename like `"Bot"`. Or you can also just create an empty folder name `sessions` and it should work well.

Hope this helps!